# After setting up Spree, cannot start new Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spree, ruby-on-rails-5

I completed the Spree tutorial and and set-up an extension named `spree_simple_sales`.  I created it in the directory of the Spree App I was creating, but problem is now I'm getting this message when I try `rails new new_app_name` (obviously not in same directory).

`Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in 'to_specs': Could not find 'spree_simple_sales' (>= 0) among 485 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)`

I'm using Rails 5.0.

Any clue what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The spree_simple_sales gem is not installed by the looks of your error. It looks like 2.0.5 is the most recent version.

In gemfile

```
gem 'spree_simple_sales', '~> 2.0.5'
```

in terminal

```
bundle udpate
bundle install
```

It looks like you need to run a generator after that

```
bundle exec rails g spree_simple_sales:install
```

Documentation for the [gem](https://github.com/crowdint/spree_simple_sales).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I didn't actually install the gem from the documentation.  (I tried above anyways but didn't work) I followed the Spree Tutorial here: http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/extensions_tutorial.html - So I created the extension which essentially becomes a gem that you plug into your Spree App.  But instead of just being an extension for that one app, it's affecting all apps on my local drive.   Hope that makes sense.